# Adding wordpress posts using phpmyadmin

Tags: posts, sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to add wordpress posts exported from phpmyadmin into a site that already has wordpress posts.

The process would work fine if the site I am trying to upload the sql file to was a brand new site with no posts or pages at all. But the site has quite some few hundred posts. And I'd like to add the sql file on top of these posts.

But every time I do so, I get an error. I think it's due to conflicting ID's. How can I get the file to upload?

Any and all suggestions are welcome.

Comment: if you create a temporary install with it, you can use the exporter/importer tool.

Comment: I agree with the temporary install, export and import to the new site.  There is no reasonable what to avoid the id collisions. Since the id's are connected to things in more than one table changing them will break things.